# Open popup automatically when navigate to the page id

Tags: html

Hi I have a custom link on menu url : #contact, and use plugin to display popup like this

```
 jQuery('a[href="#contact"]').magnificPopup({ });
```

So when im on my page I click on it and it shows popup.
but when I'm on another website (can modify) I want to navigate to this site and open popup automatically, is it possible? please help me.
I try to navigate my site to : site.com/#contact but it doesnt show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is on document ready you can check your url and based on if #contact is there on not, show popup.

Something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    if(type == 'contact'){
        //show popup
    }
}
```

Note: Check for syntax. Code not tested or tried.